# how to stop a running report in BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, oracle-apex, bi-publisher

I have a report scheduled in BIP server; it's running now but it would take very long time to complete. I just want to stop it and modify the query. but I can't find where can I stop it; can anybody help me out? How to terminate the running report without rebooting oracle DB?  Thank you!!!! (the time I post this question it has been running for 1 day now and it's still running!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supsect you'll need to ask your DBA to kill the session.

However, if you have DBA privileges yourself, you can do this by a few methods, some of which are described here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/KillingOracleSessions.php

Comment: Thank you! I think your suggestion is the only way to do that. Unfortunately I don't have dba privileges.